# what is the preferred way of getting data from an unknown class

Tags: java, reflection

data is an ArrayList of Class MyType, If use just `field.get(object)` the code doesnt compile saying unhandled exception.
When I run it, I get cannot access private members. Then I change all member fields of `MyType` to public. Then this code works. But surely there must be a better way of getting data?

```
for (Object object : data)//get one object
    {
        ArrayList<Field> fields = 
                new ArrayList<Field>(Arrays.asList(object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()));//get all its fields
        for(Field field : fields)
            {
            try {
                System.out.println(field.get(object));//print its fields value
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }

    }
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? Ideally you'd either a) know the class b) know it's a bean and (for example) use `BeanUtils` or c) have it implement a known interface then interrogate via the interface. If you're looking at raw objects without context, this is about as good as it gets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Field.setAccessible(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject%5B%5D,%20boolean%29) to allow access to private fields.

```
try {
       field.setAccessible(true);    
       System.out.println(field.get(object));//print its fields value
     } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way would be either to create an interface and to derive from this or derive from an abstract superclass. In both cases the constructs are known to the compiler.
You can get a single field with reflection by the following code:

```
Method.class.getDeclaredField(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setAccessible(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28boolean%29) on [`Field`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html), [`Method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html), and [`Constructor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html) to get access to a non-public member that the caller wouldn't normally have access to. Doing this will eliminate your error.

A more standardized approach is to use [introspection](http://da2i.univ-lille1.fr/doc/tutorial-java/javabeans/introspection/index.html). If the class follows JavaBean conventions, then you can use [`Introspector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) and [`BeanInfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html) to get [`PropertyDescriptor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html) instances, which gives you access to the public read and write methods (getters and setters) of the bean. For example, here is an example bean:

```
public class JavaBean {

    private boolean valid;
    private String name;
    private String label;

    public boolean isValid() {
        return valid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setValid(boolean valid) {
        this.valid = valid;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

Here, we declare the `valid`, `name`, and `label` properties. Note that the field names are not used to determine the names of the properties. Instead, the `get`/`is` and `set` methods are used. Also notice that primitive `boolean` properties use `is` for the getter prefix.

Then to use introspection:

```
Object unknownType = new JavaBean();
BeanInfo javaBeanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(JavaBean.class);
for (PropertyDescriptor property : javaBeanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
    System.out.println(property.getName());
}
```

This will print (not necessarily in order):

```
class
valid
name
label
```

`class` is in here because of the `getClass()` method present on all classes, so `class` is considered a property.

You can then use [`PropertyDescriptor.readMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html#getReadMethod%28%29) and [`PropertyDescriptor.writeMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html#getWriteMethod%28%29) to get the `Method` objects that are the getter and setter respectively, then use [`Method.invoke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) on them to get and set the property value for a given object using the usual reflection APIs. `PropertyDescriptor` also has some other information on it, like the property type and the property name. This is an alternative to directly using reflection. It also lets others override the `BeanInfo` that's returned by `Introspector` to be a custom implementation.